# dmultinom function for Multinomial distribution R

Tags: r, probability, multinomial

The function `dmultinom (x, size = NULL, prob, log = FALSE)` estimate probabilities of a Multinomial distribution. However, it does not run with size =1.

Theoretically, when setting size=1 the Multinomial distribution should be equivalent to the  Categorical distribution.

Does anybody know why the error message?

FYI, Categorical distribution can be modelled by dist.Categorical {LaplacesDemon}.

Examples:

`dmultinom(c(1,2,1),size = 1,prob = c(0.3,0.5,0.4))`

Error in dmultinom(c(1, 2, 1), size = 1, prob = c(0.3, 0.5, 0.4)) : 
  size != sum(x)

`dcat(c(1,2,1),p = c(0.3,0.5,0.4))`

```
[1] 0.3 0.5 0.3
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LaplacesDemon::dcat`  and `stats::dmultinom` do two different things. If you have multiple observations `dcat` takes a vector of category values, whereas `dmultinom` takes a *single vector response*, so you have to construct a matrix of responses and use `apply` (or something).

```
library(LaplacesDemon)
probs <- c(0.3,0.5,0.2)
dcat(c(1,2,1), p = probs) ## ans: 0.3 0.5 0.3
x=matrix(c(1,0,0,
           0,1,0,
           1,0,0),
         nrow=3,byrow=TRUE)
apply(x,1,dmultinom,size=1, prob=probs)
```

(I modified your example because your original probabilities, `c(0.3,0.5,0.4)`, don't add up to 1 - *neither* function gives you a warning, but `dmultinom` automatically rescales the probabilities to sum to 1)

If I try `dmultinom(c(1,2,1),p=probs, size=1)` I get

> size != sum(x)

that is, `dmultinom` is interpreting `c(1,2,1)` as "one sample from group 1, two samples from group 2, 1 from group 3", which isn't consistent with a total sample size of 1 ...

Comment: Oh, I see now. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, one more quick question.

Shouldn't prod(dcat(c(1,2,1), p = probs)) #ans 0.045
be equal to 0.3*0.5*0.5*0.2 # ans 0.015?

Comment: you're still confused. in `dcat()`, (1,2,1) doesn't mean "1 of type 1, 2 of type 2, 1 of type 3, it means "1 of type 1, then 1 of type 2, then 1 of type 1". I'm not sure what computation you're trying to do, maybe better for CrossValidated ?

Comment: Oh, ok. I get it now. It was supposed to be 0.3*0.5*0.3.
btw, I am trying to set a likelihood function. I got it now. Thank you very much again!